# Parse incrementKey making iOS app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, increment

I am trying to increment by 1 a column called "ThumbsDown" in my Parse Database, but the line of code where I perform such increment makes the app to crash. The column is of type "Number".

```
PFQuery *downvoteUser = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserRating"];
[downvoteUser whereKey:@"User" equalTo:PFUser.currentUser.username];

     NSArray *downVote = [downvoteUser findObjects];

     NSLog(@"objectID : %@", [downVote valueForKey:@"objectId"]);
     NSLog(@"ThumbsDown : %@", [downVote valueForKey:@"ThumbsDown"]);

     // Here we update the Rated column in Event Class
     PFObject *CurrentUserThumbsDown = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"UserRating" objectId:[downVote valueForKey:@"objectId"]];
     [CurrentUserThumbsDown incrementKey:@"ThumbsDown"];

     [CurrentUserThumbsDown save];
```

According to my tests :

- If I remove the incrementKey, it won't crash; but it won't do anything
- The NSLogs actually return the expected values, fetched from the cloud.
- I cant event print out the error from save, because it crashes before being able to catch it

The crash error that I get is this one:

```
2020-01-19 19:25:41.024887+0100 Sporteve[39724:418054] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2020-01-19 19:25:41.025422+0100 Sporteve[39724:418243] -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001572ef0
2020-01-19 19:25:41.027731+0100 Sporteve[39724:418243] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001572ef0'
```

**EDIT/HINT:**

- If I change the objectID in the PFObject for a real objectId from the database, it actually works, so the problem must be in the NSArray.

Comment: How many objects matching the query do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Super simple.

@Vadian asked me the correct question. I am retrieving just 1 object, so the correct line would be this one :

```
PFObject *CurrentUserThumbsDown = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"UserRating" objectId:[downVote[0] valueForKey:@"objectId"]];
```

EDIT:

A better idea provided in the comments below is to to just getFirstObject, and it is a better idea:

```
PFObject *CurrentUserThumbsDown = [downvoteUser getFirstObject];
```

Comment: A better answer is to getFirstObjectInBackground for two reasons: (1) queries should be done async (2) getFirst retrieves a single object, which is what you expect when the key being searched is unique

Comment: Why don't you use the API to return one (the first) object? And don't use `valueForKey` unless you know what KVC is and you need it. Use `objectForKey` or – available for 10 years – key subscription (`downVote[@"ThumbsDown"]`)